# Specify column width on the fist n variables where n is a variable dependent on an input selector

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have an app with a DT datatable. The table groups by some specified dimensions input by the user. Where the user specifies 1,2,3 or 4 grouping variables, I would like these variables to have a width of 100px.

The full code to reproduce is below. The specific code block in question is:

```
   output$eg_table <- DT::renderDT({my_flights_react() }, 
                                   filter = 'top', options = list(dom = 'tip',
                                                                  autoWidth = T,
                                                                  scrollX=T,
                                                                  columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px',
                                                                                         targets = 1:length(input$group_dims)))
                                                                  )
                                   )
```

If I change `1:length(input$group_dims)` to instead be `1:3` then the first 3 columns will indeed adjust to the specified length. It seems DT or Shiny cannot properly read in the length of the input input$group_dims.

How can I adjust the first n number of column widths where the number of columns is a variable dependent upon user input?

Full code to reproduce, note only the first column shows as 100px, even if I select all the fields in the selector:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(nycflights13)
library(lubridate)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Example Shiny App"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "group_dims", 
                    label =  "group_dims", 
                    choices = c("carrier", "origin", "dest", "tailnum"),
                    selected = c("carrier"),
                    multiple = T) # There can be only one
      ),

      # DT table
      mainPanel(
         DT::dataTableOutput("eg_table")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  # initial preprocessing
  my_flights <- flights %>% 
    filter(month == 11 & day >= 14) %>% # just data for 2 weeks
    mutate(date = ymd(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"))) %>% 
    select(date, carrier, origin, dest, tailnum, distance) %>% 
    mutate(date = ordered(format(date, "%d-%b"), levels = format(sort(unique(date)), "%d-%b")))


  # recative preprocessing
  my_flights_react <- reactive({
    dims <- input$group_dims
    my_flights %>%
      group_by_at(vars(date, dims)) %>%
      summarise(distance = sum(distance)) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = distance) %>%
      replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      add_column(Total = rowSums(select(., -dims), na.rm = T), .after = length(dims)) %>% 
      arrange(desc(Total))
  })


   output$eg_table <- DT::renderDT({my_flights_react() }, 
                                   filter = 'top', options = list(dom = 'tip',
                                                                  autoWidth = T,
                                                                  scrollX=T,
                                                                  columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px',
                                                                                         targets = 1:length(input$group_dims)))
                                                                  )
                                   )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your minimal example is working OK. The columns are wider than without the `columnsDef` bit. (Selecting tailgate throws an error, but that's besides the point.)

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Odd. I've added a screen shot. It's not working for me locally :/
Perhaps the code is sound but there's something up with my local set up.